# Github workflow file fails when pushed but succeeds locally

Tags: python, docker, unit-testing, github-actions

I have a project which consists of an API and some other services. I've created a Unittest file to test the health of the API on each push to the Github repository. The test file is run in a Docker container(so to isolate it from the other services). The API is of course also in a container.

When I run the api test container locally(docker-compose up api-test-runner) it works fine and has no problems what so ever. When I push the project to the GitHub repository it fails with error code 500, which indicates a server error.

I've included the workflow file below.

Workflow file:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: API Test

# Define in which situiations and on what branches the workflow should be ran.
on:
  push:
    branches:
     - "*"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "*"

jobs:
  api-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      # Build the docker image
      - name: Build Docker images
        run: docker-compose up --build -d api db

      # Health check to make sure the application is ready to accept requests
      - name: Wait for application to be ready
        run: |
          until curl --silent --fail http://localhost:4000/health; do
            echo 'Waiting for application to be ready...'
            sleep 5
          done

      # Run the python test script in an isolated docker container
      - name: Run API tests
        run: docker-compose up api_test_runner

      # Checks that results of tests passed, if not, throw error.
      - name: Check test results
        run: if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

In the file there is a **Build the docker image**, which builds the api and database service. A **Health check to make...** to send a request to a simple route on the api to test its health(after adding this the workflow job won't complete because it gets stuck in the loop, indicating that the service never gets operational). The **Run the python test...** runs the api test container service. The **Checks that results of tests...** is there to check the results of the test container(this, for some reason, doesn't catch the error at all, it passes the Python test even when the error code isn't 0. ).

For anyone that wants to view the Compose.yaml file, here it is:

```
# Instructions for running the application
# ======== Basic app startup ========
# 1. start application services: ´docker-compose up api db -d´

# ======== Running API test locally ========
# (Note: application services have to be running before running the tests)
#
# 1. start application services: ´docker-compose up api db -d´
# 2. run tests: ´docker-compose up api_test_runner´

version: '3.9'

services:

  # <======== Application services ========>

  # ======== API container ========
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: justingav/d0020e:latest
    environment:
      - DB_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      # ports being listened on
      - "4000:4000"
  # ================================

  # ====== Database container ======
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:latest
    #volumes:
    #  - /home/upload/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  # ================================

  # <========= Test runner service =========>
  api_test_runner:
    container_name: api_test_runner
    build:
      context: ./api_test_runner
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api_test_runner:/api_test_runner
    depends_on:
      - db
      - api
    # run tests on startup
    command: [ "python", "-m", "unittest", "api_test" ]
  # ================================

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
```

I've tried tracking the issue using a health check, getting the docker logs of the services, adding a check in the api file to check its operation(see code below),

```
try:
    # Your existing code to start the Flask application
    logging.info('Starting application...')
    api.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000)
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception('Failed to start application')
```

This doesn't seem to be helpful tho.

We can at least come to the conclusion that the api file and api-test-runner file aren't the issue since they work fine locally, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In your `curl`, can you try replacing the `localhost` with `api`, or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @Skenvy Absolutely. Tried `api`, `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0`, they all yielded the same result as before(that is, stuck in an infinite loop). The Docker logs of the api service don't seem to say anything, indicates to me that it might not be starting up at all(the api service that is).